# How to simplify Swift Codable Struct for nested JSON?

Tags: json, swift, codable

I have a json like this.

```
{
  "connectType": "CALL",
  "connectFrequency": "WEEKLY",
  "status": {
    "status": "On"
  }
}
```

I am trying to parse it using `Codable` in `Swift`. I can think of it like below :

```
struct Preference : Codable {
    let connectFrequency : String?
    let connectType : String?
    let status : PreferenceStatus?
}

struct PreferenceStatus : Codable {
    let status : String?
}
```

Now when I have to check `status` on/off value, I will have to go like `obj.status?.status`. What I would ideally want is to remove the nesting since its only a single value inside the `PreferenceStatus`.

Is there a way to define my model like below using the same json :

```
struct Preference : Codable {
    let connectFrequency : String?
    let connectType : String?
    let status : String?
}
```

I'm new to `Codable` paradigm. Please assist. Thanks.

Comment: First, avoid the use of optionals if you know that your json will always contain those keys. In order to simplify the struct in the way you want you will need to implement custom decoding

Comment: Custom decoding or add a computed property to your struct, for example `var isOn: Bool { status?.status == "On" }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To flatten the structure you have to decode the JSON *manually*. `status` can be decoded as enum. `connectFrequency` and `connectType` seem to be enums, too.

```
let jsonString = """
{
  "connectType": "CALL",
  "connectFrequency": "WEEKLY",
  "status": {
    "status": "On"
  }
}
"""

enum Frequency : String, Decodable {
   case hourly = "HOURLY", weekly = "WEEKLY"
}

enum Status : String, Decodable {
   case off = "Off", on = "On"
}

struct Preference : Decodable {
    let connectFrequency : Frequency
    let connectType : String
    let status : Status
    
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case connectFrequency, connectType, status }
    
    init(from decoder : Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        connectFrequency = try container.decode(Frequency.self, forKey: .connectFrequency)
        connectType = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .connectType)
        let nestedContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .status)
        status = try nestedContainer.decode(Status.self, forKey: .status)
    }
}

let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)

do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Preference.self, from: data)
    print(result)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```